# How to get subtopic related to Community topic in apex?

Tags: apex, community, topics

Have set of Topics and subtopics in community, I would like to get the subtopic related to particular topic throw apex code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a method for it ConnectApi ([reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedTopics_static_methods.htm)). I think you need to use that.

```
ConnectApi.ManagedTopicCollection topics = ConnectApi.ManagedTopics.getManagedTopics(communityId);
for (ConnectApi.ManagedTopic managedTopic : topics.managedTopics) {
    System.debug('###managedTopic.topic.name = ' + ((ConnectApi.Topic)managedTopic.topic).name);

    Set<String> topicNames = new Set<String>();
    for (ConnectApi.ManagedTopic childManagedTopic : managedTopic.children) {
        topicNames.add(((ConnectApi.Topic)childManagedTopic.topic).name + '\n');
    }

    System.debug('### childTopicNames:\n' + String.join(topicNames, '\n'));
}
```

Comment: @nubie added code that should do the trick)

Comment: I am getting error like `Illegal value for parameter: 'communityId': 09a6F000000tfvzQAA`

Comment: am trying to pass community id but getting error

Comment: @nubie Because this is CommunityId and you need to pass there NetworkId. Use SOQL to query your Network and get its' id. Ye, I know it's not really intuitive)

Comment: Now i am able to get the topic but , I am not getting the subtopic it's showing 0 child @ytiq

Comment: Then it doesn't have subtopics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102296/discussion-between-ytiq-and-nubie).

Answer (score 1):

The children become visible when you provide the depth parameter

```
Integer depth =2;
ConnectApi.ManagedTopicCollection topics = ConnectApi.ManagedTopics.getManagedTopics(communityId,ConnectApi.ManagedTopicType.Navigational,depth);
```